# Почему тормозит визуальный редактор страниц wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Возникла проблема с визуальным редактором страниц в wordpress - при попытке отредактировать, создать, опубликовать новую или старую страницу wordpress начинает жутко тормозить и отлипает минут через 10.

> Я подчеркну что проблема именно только с редактированием и созданием
>   страниц. Если открывать редактор записей - то проблем не наблюдается.

Остальные разделы wordpress работают как и положено - без тормозов. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что ресурсов - хватает.

После чего возникла проблема?

Проблема появилась после того, как было загружено через плагин WP All Import - более 25000 страниц

Действия которые были предприняты:

- полное отключение всех плагинов
- отключение дополнительных элементов в редакторе страниц wordpress (Настройки экрана → Атрибуты страницы, Изображения страницы, Произвольные поля, Обсуждения, Ярлык, Автор)

Ничего из проведенных действий не помогло исправить ситуацию.

Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Была похожая проблема, когда работали с Elementor. Решилось переустановкой вордпресса через консоль->обновления->переустановить